# Is there any API to integrate FEDEX?

Tags: fedex

Currently i am in need to integrate FEDEX API in my project. I searched a lot in google. But i cant able to find perfect one. could any one help me to resolve this problem...

Thanks in Advance...

Fero

Comment: Might help to specify what platform and language you are working with as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some resources on the [Fedex Developer Resource Center](http://fedex.com/us/developer/product/solutions.html) you may find helpful

What region are you looking for and what type of features do you need?

Based on your comment, looks like the [*FedEx Web Services*](https://www.fedex.com/fcl/;SHIPPINGSESSIONID=HLqjKNJNSCXKXv9Q5L3n6Qdgh7ySXdhctY8y6gvdr5nX2D1wsyYR!-1704109444?appName=fclfsm&locale=us_en&step3URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fedex.com%2Fshipping%2FshipEntryAction.do%3Fmethod%3DdoRegistration%26link%3D1%26locale%3Den_US%26urlparams%3Dus%26sType%3DF&returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fedex.com%2Fshipping%2FshipEntryAction.do%3Fmethod%3DdoEntry%26link%3D1%26locale%3Den_US%26urlparams%3Dus%26sType%3DF&programIndicator=0) are what you're after, you'll need to sign up and login to be sure though.

Comment: region-> United States. Features-> For Shipping

Comment: Thanks seller.. I got the sample code in Fedex Developer Resource Center.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to get in touch with FedEx directly, and depending on what you are doing, I don't remember it being free.

EDIT: This might help you out: [FedEx Developer Resource Center](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the sample PHP code from Fedex Developer Resource Center.

Answer (score 0):

There is also what is known as the FEDEX WEB INTEGRATION WIZARD (FWIW). It will help you create a shipping/rating/tracking page for your website through a 'wizard' tool. It requires you to request this from Fedex and they provide a contact to help you through it. Fedex does not charge for this if you are a customer with an account

Comment: This has been phased out as of Q3 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can also find some packages with wrappers for such APIs.

For example, [there is a wrapper for .Net](https://github.com/kylewest/DotNetShipping), which also implements UPS and USPS APIs in addition to FedEx