# Has anyone integrated Fedex web services into their website?

Tags: php, web-services, fedex

I have to set this up so that users can make labels, and track shipments, can someone outline the steps of how this works, including any interaction I need to do in regards to testing and contacting Fedex support, any special keys, gotchas?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304561/is-there-any-api-to-integrate-fedex

Answer (score 1):

Integrating with any web service is simply a matter of reading the available documentation for that service. There's really no shortcut, I'm afraid. As indicated in the answers referenced by Changeling, all the answers you're looking for are available at http://fedex.com/us/developer/.

Here's probably a better place to start, actually:
http://www.fedex.com/us/office/copyprint/online/webservices/

Comment: I'm aware that I will have to read the documentation, but it would be beneficial if someone who had implemented this in the past could provide some general advice on the process, I'm not asking for an entire solution but just a helpful paragraph or two on the process.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed the fedex application using the fedex API.

Its very important to read the doucmentation and prepare your notes like what kind of special services are woking with the shipment types.As mere reading documentation is really confusing for the new starter.

Perpare your tree then follow the samples provided by fedex which helps you in proceeding.

regards,
sunny

Comment: if possible check the fedex online shipment form at fedex.com website and read the help provided inside the form against every field.This will be really helpfull in understanding.
sunny